# How to center align combobox selected item in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I want combobox selected item alone center aligned while the drop down contents to be left aligned.

To achieve this I made an entire copy of the  default combobox and modified the Content Presenter of Toggle button horizontal alignment to Center

Is there any simple approach to achieve this than to edit the entire template

Comment: In short, no there is no simple way of doing this other than changing the control template. @XAML Lover's answer works for changing the alignment of the selected item in the drop down (the popup), but will not affect the alignment of the item displayed in the toggle button.

Comment: Thanks, I used control template only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning the HorizontalAlignment = "Center" in the ContentPresenter in  ControlTemplate of the ComboBox

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                
           <Popup ...... />
           <ToggleButton ...../>
           <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach that worked for me :

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to do this without having to re-template the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="Visible">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

`<ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">` will set all items to be centered by default- the ones in the drop down list, and the one that's in the selection box.

The `DataTrigger` in the `ComboBoxItem` style looks for a `ComboBox` parent somewhere in the visual tree. Since the drop down list is inside a `Popup`, which is not part of the main visual tree, this `DataTrigger` will always fail for non-selected items. The *selected* item *is* shown inside the `ComboBox` as part of the main visual tree, so the `DataTrigger` for that one item succeeds, and that one item gets aligned `Left`.

The `Visibility` part is somewhat arbitrary. I needed some property that I could predict the value of, so the `DataTrigger` would always activate if the `Combobox` source was found. In this case, `Visibility` won't necessarily always be `Visible`, but when it isn't, you can't see the alignment anyway, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a trigger associated to the style of ComboBoxItem.

```
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: No actually its not working , the content was still then left aligned only

Comment: Are you sure this Style applied to your ComboBoxItem?

Comment: Yes,Actually it center aligns the previously selected item in the combo drop down,but I need only the selected item in the toggle button to be center aligned and the elements in the drop down to be left aligned

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.