# WPF ComboBox: Align selected value and/or drop down items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, right-align

I have an almost default WPF ComboBox:

[image]

What is the simplest way to align items, for instance, to the right **in combobox's input and/or drop down?**

I've looked around and found only solutions messing with the control templates which in my opinion is too long shot for such a simple thing. I can't believe there is no simpler solution we can do for aligning the items.

**UPDATE**:
I've slightly reformulated the question to cover a broader set of cases further readers might experience on this topic as it turned out thanks to dkozl's answer.

Also, it should prevent some people from trying to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center align combobox selected item in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576488/how-to-center-align-combobox-selected-item-in-wpf)

Comment: @MethodMan: No, that thread about `How to center align combobox **selected item** in WPF` - in combobox input, not in dropdown.

Comment: I know that just change the value from Center to `Right` come on now

Comment: @MethodMan: If you're talking about that accepted answer - it messes with `ControlTemplate` which is a long shot in my opinion as I've intentionally mentioned in my question. So, my question is formulated from the beginning so that it's not a duplicate of the one you're talking about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to right align **both selected value and drop down items** then setting `HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"` against `ComboBox` should be enough

```xml
<ComboBox ... HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
```

if you want to right align **only drop down items** then you need to change `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the `ComboBoxItem`

```xml
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

and to right align **only selected value** combination of both

```xml
<ComboBox ... HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: By some reason, setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` against `ComboBox` solely did the trick: both selected value and drop down items became aligned to the right. So there is no need to change `ItemContainerStyle` as far as I can see.

Comment: True. Updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! And for completeness for further readers: how to right align only the selected value, but left the drop down items alignment as is?

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both things from dkozl's answer and by some reason setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` against my `ComboBox` was sufficient to align to the right items in both combobox's input and drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of aligning the selected item on the right, so that users can always see the end of the string.
Simplest solution I found was the following

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding textProp}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```